# How to grow a passionfruit vine from seed

Tags: seeds, germination, seed-starting

I'd like to try growing a passionfruit vine from seed. My best guess on a good way to do it would be to dry the seed out well first, then soak it for a day or two to help it germinate, then put it under the some soil in a seed tray.

Is there a better technique?

Answer (score 3):

According to Norman Deno in [*Seed Germination Theory and Practice* (2nd Edition)](http://www.scribd.com/doc/44360991/SEED-GERMINATION-THEORY-AND-PRACTICE-by-Professor-Norman-C-Deno), the seeds of passion fruit (*Passiflora edulis*) germinate best if they are provided a moist, warm (70ºF, 21ºC) period for three months, followed by a cold, moist (40ºF, 4ºC) period for three months, followed finally by a moist, warm (70ºF, 21ºC) period (81% germination in the fifth week following the last temperature change).

In his [*First Supplement to Seed Germination Theory and Practice*](http://www.scribd.com/doc/46330980/Seed-Germination-Theory-and-Practice-1st-Supplement-Norman-Deno), Deno added the following information:

> *P. edulis* had been found to germinate in a 70-40-70 pattern (2nd Ed.). Thelma Norman of Mena, Arizona, now reports some interesting results. Commercial seeds of *P. edulis*, *P. antiquiensis*, *P. malformis*, *P. mollissima*, and *P. vitafolia* were inadvertently exposed to temperatures of 125ºF for several days shortly after sowing. All germinated in 6-10 days. Presumably the chemical system blocking germination can be destroyed not only by 70-40 treatments, but also by high temperatures in the 125ºF region. *P. cinnabarina* and *P. coccinea* failed to germinate in the above treatment.

I, personally, suspect that, for passion fruit and some other fussy germinators, fresh seed may germinate more easily.

Answer (score 3):

I grew passiflora alata from seed a few years ago.  The seeds were dry (purchased from a garden store).  My method for fussy seeds like this is to put them in a ziplock bag with some damp sphagnum moss.  When they start to germinate they can be potted into small containers.  I find that putting them right into soil makes them harder to keep moist and also harder to see what is going on.